# Communication between Flex and Java?

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex

Is there any way a Adobe Flash Builder could call methods from a java class?

Without any servers? just like a API where i could call use methods from java clasees?

Comment: You're question is unclear. Do you want to call java methods from your Flex Code or from the Flash Builder?

Comment: i am trying to develop an desktop application from flash builder 4.5 .  i will like to call java methods from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [RemoteObject](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_4.html), [WebService](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_4.html), or [HTTPService](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_2.html) to call a backend server from within a Flex application.

If you want to run Java code on the desktop, if that is the need, but using Adobe AIR and [NativeProcess](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/interacting_with_native_process.html).

Comment: NativeProcess required the Adobe Air application to be categorize as extended desktop ?

Comment: i am referring to the abobe profile [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS144092a96ffef7cc16ddeea2126bb46b82f-8000.html)

Comment: Probably, but I'm not sure  I'll add links to my answer.

Comment: okay. Thanks for you help. I have another question posted. If you know the answer, hope you wouldn't mind helping [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075085/adobe-air-native-process-with-java)

Answer (score 0):

Native process allows to execute .exe file from Adobe Air,

One good example is wil be [EXAMPLE}(http://mariusht.com/blog/2010/03/17/air-2-0-native-process-with-java-program/)

NOTE : Remember to add  extendedDesktop in the application-app.xml file. As native process is