# Adobe Air Native Process with Java

Tags: java, apache-flex, air, native, native-methods

Does Adobe Air Native process only allows to call .exe file only which runs a java class ?

And not accessing a certain method in the java class?

Comment: Question : Does Adobe's Native Process allows me to call Just a JAVA Class METHOD ? And not the .exe or .jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run java applications by running `java.exe` with native process and passing appropriate arguments.
See [Running java from cmd](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/javaindos.html).

Comment: sorry if i was unclear, does it allow me to call just a Method in the java class?

Comment: That's not so easy. In principle you can write C and compile to a DLL which can be invoked by Adobe Air directly (version 4.6 onwards) and this C source invokes Java by JNI.

Comment: The arguments you pass to your .jar can indicate what to do; otherwise, you can write a native extension like nalply mentioned, which would be more difficult.